# Java maven project in debian VPS server: when I clone the git repo in my local machine I get a maven project with a wrong java version

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, versioning, projects-and-solutions

I have a VPS server which hosts a java/maven web application. The application was not written by me.

In the VPS server I have a git repository to get the source of the application. I have cloned the repository in my local machine directly in an eclipse project, so that I can start coding, but I have a problem.

For some reason, eclipse uses jre 1.5, and so the source code is full of error. The reason is that many method of implemented interfaces have the "Override" attribute, as follows.

The example interface

```
public interface myInterface(){
    public void doSomething();
}
```

The example class

```
public class myClass implements myInterface{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        performAction();
    }
}
```

And in jre 1.5 you can not override a method of an interface, and so of course you have an error.

I don't know what is the version target, but it's obvious that the progammer didn't write the application on jre 1.5, because the source code works in the VPS environment.
I see that in the VPS enviromnemt the installed java version is 1.8.

I have two questions.

1) How can I force eclipse to use the right version, instead of using a random version which isn't obviously correct?

2) In reality the first point doesn't worry me so much: I could simply change the java version in my local project (I have tried and it works), but I'm afraid that when I commit my new code it could create damages in the remote code. 
The question is: is the java version of my local project relevant when it comes to commit? Will eclipse simply commit the source code, or will it try to change the java version in the remote code, in a way that it could create damages in the deployed application?

Note: to clone the git repository I did the following:
1) File -> Import
2) Maven -> Ceck out Maven Projects from SCM
3) I changed the default SCM connector with "egit", so that I could get the maven project from git
4) I cloned the repository
5) I got a project as the one you can see in the image below

Note "JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]"

[image: My project]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Java version in the `pom.xml` file under the project properties. That way, Eclipse will know what version you're expecting to use in your project.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

[More on it here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).